# How to add dynamic text as Taskbar Icon overlay?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-7, icons, taskbar

I'm trying add Taskbar Icon overlay with text to windows7 application icon, I did manage to add small overlay but unable to add the text.

Does any one know how to add dynamic text as Taskbar Icon overlay?

Using: WPF and C#

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only add an `Image` so you have to create that:

```
    RectangleF rectF = new RectangleF(0, 0, 40, 40);
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(40, 40, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
    g.FillRectangle(System.Drawing.Brushes.White, 0, 0, 40, 40);
    g.DrawString("5", new Font("Arial", 25), System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, new PointF(0, 0));

    IntPtr hBitmap = bitmap.GetHbitmap();

    ImageSource wpfBitmap =
        Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
            hBitmap, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty,
            BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

    TaskbarItemInfo.Overlay = wpfBitmap;
```