# How add a skype-like notification count to a c# program icon

Tags: c#, notifications, skype

I'm working on a project and we'd like to add a notification count the way skype does.

A number pops near the icon in the windows taskbar to indicate how many messages the user have received.
This is the result we're trying to achieve: http://it.tinypic.com/r/2guclkk/8

Looking around the internet haven't led to anything, so is there any API I can use in C# to achieve this?

Comment: I solved using the WindowsAPICodePack: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081665/windows-api-code-pack-where-is-it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved using the WindowsAPICodePack: [Windows API Code Pack: Where is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081665/windows-api-code-pack-where-is-it)

The method is `SetIconOverlay()`:

```
public void SetOverlayIcon(IntPtr windowHandle, Icon icon, string accessibilityText);
```

Comment: I am using forms in my app and i had downloaded WindowsAPICodePack through Visual studio PM console. Should i need to add any more references before i use SetOverlayIcon API, as it is not detecting it as a known method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that in taskbar, you might want to use overlay icons, which are described here, if you are using WPF: [How to add dynamic text as Taskbar Icon overlay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292506/how-to-add-dynamic-text-as-taskbar-icon-overlay)
If you are using Forms you might want to use this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shell.taskbariteminfo.overlay%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

If you want to do the same in system tray, it is a duplicit question: [How can I overlay system-tray icon ? WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27011627/how-can-i-overlay-system-tray-icon-wpf/32359010#32359010), and the answer is probably to draw the desired number at runtime to the icon and change the system tray icon.